# Anonymous Inner Class in Groovy not capturing final outer variable state

Tags: multithreading, groovy

I'm running a test where I take 1,000 Strings that represent an ID. I create an `ExecutorService` with 100 threads, loop over the 1,000 Strings, and create a `Callable` for each. This works fine in Java, but I found in Groovy that the anonymous inner class `Callable` is not storing the iterated value.

Here is my test:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

class CallableTest {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        CallableTest test = new CallableTest();

        test.runTest();
    }

    public List<String> setupTest(){

        List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            ids.add( "ID_" + i );
        }

        return ids;
    }

    public void runTest() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
        List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
        List<String> ids = setupTest();

        for(final String id : ids) {
            Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
                @Override
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    return doSomethingWithId(id);
                }
            });

            futures.add( future );

        }

        for(Future<String> future : futures) {
            String message = future.get();
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }

    public String doSomethingWithId(String id) {
        return "Doing something with ID: " + id;
    }
}
```

The problem in Groovy is here:

```
for(final String id : ids) {
    Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            // The ID value here is not the ID value from when the Callable was created 
            return doSomethingWithId(id);
        }
    });

    futures.add( future );

}
```

As you can see in my comment, the `id` value when calling the method `doSomethingWithId` is not the same value as it was when the `Callable` was created. This leads to `Doing something with ID: ID_999` being printed majority of the time.

If I copy this over to a Java project and run it, it runs as expected. I get `Doing something with ID: ID_x` from 0-999 with no duplicates.

Why doesn't this work in Groovy? My understanding is that Groovy should support anonymous inner classes, but it appears that the anonymous inner class `Callable` is not capturing the outer variable `id` state when it creates the anonymous class. I'm using Java 7 with Groovy 2.3.10.

**UPDATE**
I found that adding the following made this work:

```
for(final String id : ids) {

    final String myId = id // This makes it work

    Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return doSomethingWithId(myId);
        }
    });

    futures.add( future );

}
```

Seems like Groovy isn't actually making the value returned from the iterator final?

Comment: I run your example with Java 7.0.191-zulu and Groovy 2.3.10 - it worked as expected, none of the IDs got duplicated. I run this example several times just to make sure it was not an accident.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak thanks for the reply. That is odd you aren't seeing it. I just tried it with `jdk1.8.0_121` and `Groovy 2.3.10` on `Windows 7`. This time I used 10 IDs and only 2 threads. I got `Doing something with ID: ID_1` 1 time and `Doing something with ID: ID_9` 9 times. Again, the final declaration fixes it. For whatever reason, it isn't implicitly saving the value of the iterated `id` when creating the anonymous class.